# Is there a quaternionic analogue of Weyl's character formula?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters, quaternions

I am pondering about this. The definition of a character makes sense for quaternionic matrices. Indeed, given a quaternionic representation of a quaternionic matrix group such as $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$ or $Sp(m)$, it makes sense to talk about its character, since the trace of a quaternionic matrix is well defined.

However, the determinant of a quaternionic matrix is not well defined due to ordering ambiguities (since $\mathbb{H}$ is of course non-abelian). From what I recall some definitions have been put forward, each with its drawbacks. I could be wrong and if so, please provide some details if you can.

My question is whether or not there is a quaternionic analogue of Weyl's character formula. A very special case is of course the Vandermonde formula. Does it have a quaternionic analogue? And then maybe we can build from there...

Comment: If a quaternionic representation is a sum of two conjugate complex representations, then its quaternionic character can (probably) be recovered from the complex character of either original representation.  So I guess this is just a question of the "quaternionic lift" of the complex character of a quaternionic complex representation.

Comment: @LSpice, I am trying to understand your comment. To me, a character in this case is in general quaternion-valued. It is the sum of the diagonal elements, which are quaternions. Just making sure we are on the same page. Can you maybe give an example or explain a bit more please?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1212015), I believe that, if the quaternion representation $V$ is the sum of a complex representation $V'$ and its complex conjugate $V'j$, then $\Theta_{V, \mathbb H}(g)$ equals $\Theta_{V', \mathbb C}(g)(1 + j)$.  If that's not exactly true, then surely something like it is.  But, if $V$ is irreducible as a complex representation, then the best we can say is that $\Theta_{V, \mathbb H}(g)$ equals $\operatorname{tr}_{\mathbb H/\mathbb C}(\Theta_{V, \mathbb C}(g))$.

Comment: @LSpice, if we take as group $GL(1, \mathbb{H})$, and consider its $1$-dimensional quaternionic representation. Given an imaginary quaternion $x$, the character of the previous representation at $x$ is nothing but $e^x$, a unit quaternion, which can be written as a complex $2$ by $2$ matrix in the "usual" way. Its trace over the complex numbers is $2 \cosh(\lVert x \rVert)$, which in particular is real and positive. But knowing the norm of $x$ doesn't give us information about the direction of $x$ and thus we cannot from that knowledge deduce $e^x$, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1212029), yes, I agree (except that I don't think that I agree that the complex trace of a unit quaternion is always a positive real number); there is a question here that needs to be addressed.  I think my saying "[this is just a question …](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1212014)" made it sound dismissive, which I didn't intend.  I didn't mean that the question was a formal manipulation, only that we didn't have to consider the other case (where a quaternionic representation decomposes into two conjugate complex representations).

Comment: @LSpice, no worries. Correction, I think the complex trace is probably $2\cos(\lVert x \rVert)$ (not hyperbolic cosine), so yes, it is real, but it can definitely be positive, negative or zero. And no need to apologize, or something. I just didn't understand your comment well. For example, I don't know what the notation $\operatorname{tr}_{\mathbb{H}/\mathbb{C}}$ means. I will email you and ask you if you don't mind. Also, in my previous comment, the representation is irreducible and so does not satisfy your hypothesis. It is definitely not a counterexample (my bad!).